# how to update h:inputtext in jsf

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

in Jquery i am sending value to managed bean with success

```
document.getElementById('formId:inputId').value = "blavla";
document.getElementById('formId:someId').click();
```

and my jsf code is :

```
 <h:inputText id="inputId" value="#{gestionduplanning.testvalue}" >
 <f:ajax/>
 </h:inputText>
 <h:inputText id="inputId3" value="#{gestionduplanning.testvalue2}" /> 

 <h:commandButton id="someId" value="Button" action="{gestionduplanning.exec2(gestionduplanning.testvalue)}" style="display:none">
 <f:ajax render="someId" execute="@all"/>  
 </h:commandButton>
```

and my managed bean methode :

```
   public void exec2(String x) {

    this.testvalue2 = testvalue;   

   }
```

the problem is when i give the value of testvalue to testvalue2 i have nothing .

how i can give the value to this value and be showen in the `h:inputText`

Comment: What's the scope of your managed bean? (by the way this should work with `this.testvalue2 = x;`)

Comment: @ViewScoped i changed to SessionScoped but same problem

Comment: Didn't you forget about getters and setters for the bean properties?

Comment: no i have them . the real problem is when i change a bean value didnt change in the inputText <h:inputText id="inputId3" value="#{gestionduplanning.testvalue2}" /> : this.testvalue2 = testvalue; but the inputtext for testvalue2 still have same value didnt change.

Comment: Let me get this straight: you change the bean value for `inputId3` but you cannot see it on the client side? If so, that's because `render` should be `inputId3` not `someId`.

Comment: @marouanoviche , why dont you change `<f:ajax render="someId" execute="@all"/>`  into `<f:ajax render="inputId3" execute="@all"/> `?

Answer (score 1):

I did it with `Primefaces` before. Maybe It can help you;

Here is my code part in page;

```
<p:commandButton id="linkButton2" process=":form:receivedMessage"
            style="display:none" />

<h:inputText id="receivedMessage" style="display:none"></h:inputText>
```

And the `Javascript` code part;

```
document.getElementById('form:receivedMessage').value = 'myValue';
document.getElementById('form:linkButton2').click();
```

These code parts worked for me to send data from javascript to backing managed bean.

When your command button is clicked your bean variable will also be filled by input value. So you don't need to send it as a function parameter.

Comment: the problem the <inputText change when i change it from the Jquery but when i changed from Managed bean didnt change